# Is it possible to add a beep sound to google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, beep

Is there anyway of adding a beep sound or alarm sound when a Google sheet is updated or cell updated if the sheet is open on another computer? Preferably by scripting as my company restricts use of add on apps.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot. But I really am not the type to know.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think there was but you never know.

Answer (score 0):

OK. This is an easy, but round-a-bout way to accomplish your beep when a cell is updated. Don't know how to do it for when others are viewing. Zapier doesn't offer that trigger:

1. Go Zapier.
2. Select Google Drive, and Push Bullet (or some service where you want to be alerted from with sound). The Drive Trigger should be cell updated.
3. Set the sound on for whichever alert you choose from Zapier.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Sadly the free option only offers 100zaps a month. This sheet will do that in a day and before paying would need a trial period of a few months. Thanks anyways.